Update Items property of Gallery on Selection of gallery Item to auto-Update Gallery on same Screen without Navigating to new Screen
Is there any way to update the "Items" property of a Gallery, to kind of perform async on the Gallery without navigating to new screen
Items= [Category_Name:"C1", Category_Name:"C2", Category_Name:"C3"]

So if I could do something like:
Items= If(Gallery.Selected.Category_Name<>"C1",
    [Category_Name:"sub1_C1", Category_Name:"sub2_C1"],
    [Category_Name:"C1", Category_Name:"C2", Category_Name:"C3"]
)

But it is not possible... Please suggest work around to get this done. Thanks!

Why not try using collection for gallery and used if condition with ClearCollect to fill data in gallery.  Just an idea to try and find.

So if I understand correctly, based on the selection gallery should auto-update its item property, ryt?
